# How do I integrate Yammer into our intranet website

Tags: api, enterprise, yammer

We are using the Enterprise version of Yammer. I am going to start integrating yammer into our intranet website. The documentation page here says to first register an app: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/app-registration

Is this still applicable even if we are using the Enterprise version and the tool will be integrated with an intranet website?

Part of my confusion comes from the below line where MS Support explains one of the difference of Enterprise version from the free one:

> Network Level Apps and Integrations >Authorize and manage apps for
>   your network. Access advanced integrations like SharePoint, Single
>   Sign-On, and Directory Sync.

Does Enterprise version provide an admin interface to create/register/manage your apps? I don't yet have access to admin tools. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Yammer embed](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/embed) to integrate yammer into intranet websites. Embed is specifically designed for this purpose and you do not need to create/register any application. That said, if Embed does not suite your requirements, you'd need to develop your own custom application using Yammer REST APIs; this will require you to register an app. Further details and sample codes can be found [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/israelo/archive/2014/10/21/yammer-js-sdk-for-dummies.aspx).

App registration is independent of the network's subscription type.